# Buttons all disabled if user clicks "submit" without filling out form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website if you hit the "Send Pledge" button and click out of the following prompt for your credit card, all of the buttons (the close button, send pledge button, even the add card button) are all disabled. However, this error never occurs when using the exact same code on LiveWeave or jsfiddle...

Here is the link to my website where it is NOT working: www.cantedpictures.com/10test/

Again, click "Send Pledge" first, and whether or not you fill out the credit card information, all of the buttons will be disabled, even if you click out of the overlay and reopen it.

Here is a link where the code is functional:
http://liveweave.com/XTfaQm

I am very new to all of this, so I apologize if the answer is straight-forward. Please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a javascript error on your website. Did you try correcting that?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined           ?/js/global/1.1.05/:1132
```

Comment: Just curious, how did you catch this error? Didn't find it and still trying to work it out. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: I just went and  hit the "Send Pledge" button and saw that error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code, seems there is a semicolon missing on line 59 of the shared link.

Comment: thank you! I fixed this error as well as the extra comma. Still didn't fix the button being disabled though.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue! I had another code that was overriding the other javascript. Thanks everyone for the response! :)